# sql developer stored procedure running without error

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

**BEGIN
PROC_TEST('20-10-2020');
END;**

I tried to execute this procedure,After executing output shows **anonymous block completed.** with out any error
but it is actually not compiled.
how solve this problem?

Comment: An anonymous block can only complete if it first compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled? You just *executed* an anonymous PL/SQL block which calls a procedure named `PROC_TEST` and passed a string as a parameter. I guess you meant to pass a `DATE` instead. Did you? If so, try

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  proc_test(date '2020-10-20');
end;
/
```

instead.

Procedure executed successfully, regardless.

If you expected some kind of an output (via `dbms_output.put_line`, for example), enable serveroutput (like in my example, which works in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or maybe some other tools as well; if not, enable it via GUI you use).

Finally, I don't see any problem here to be solved. What exactly do you have on mind?